# Why won't iTunes stream 320 kbps audio across a network?

Tags: itunes

My iTunes library, that's shared on our network, has some songs that have a bit rate of 320 kbps.  These songs will not play when I try to play them from a client computer - accessing them through the Shared library.

Why won't they play?  Is there a work around besides downgrading the bit rate?

Comment: Are the non-playing songs DRM'd?

Comment: Nope.  Just non-DRM'd MP3s.

Comment: The problem is not the bitrate. Apple streams lossless files (above 1000kbps) perfectly fine.
Please specify "won't play". Is there an error? Are they greyed out? Does playback stutter?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know for sure it is the 320 kbps that is keeping the songs from being played? Can you play songs with a lower bitrate successfully?

There are three reasons I can think of that would make a song not play in Shared Library:

- You have reached the 5-computer limit
  on Shared Library. Only when the
  number of concurrent connections gets
  back to less than 5 you will be able
  to connect and play the songs.
- The remote iTunes has not been
  authorized for that Apple ID and the
  song you are trying to play has DRM
  protection (i.e., it is an Audible
  book or it was purchased way back
  when Apple only sold DRM-protected
  songs).
- The song is listed on the Shared
  Library (and on the "server" iTunes
  Library) but it is pointing to a file
  that does not exist on the computer's
  file system or is out of reach.

I hope this gives you additional ideas to look into.

Comment: Other songs play fine.  The only thing in common with songs that don't play is the 320 kbps bit rate.  These are all non-DRM'd MP3 files.  They all play fine on the host computer so, I know that they are pointed to the right place.

Comment: Also look at the encoder. If possible (i.e. if you ripped them yourself) maybe try another encoder, preferable iTunes itself.

Comment: Extending on @XQYZ's comment, you should be able to right click the songs inside of iTunes and transcode them. If this doesn't work, try the file menu then find the encode to menu.

Answer (score 0):

On the clients, try to switch the 'Streaming buffer size' (*Preferences > Advanced*) to 'Large', it may help if it's a bandwidth problem.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.  Made sense though...

Comment: local networks should not have a bandwidth problem with 360kbps as most get between 100Mbps to 1Gbps.

Comment: @TravisPessetto wired ones perhaps-- wi-fi ones do not.

Comment: @whiskeychief wifi theoretically can be that fast.  Wireless n has theoretical speeds of 300Mbps and wireless ac even faster.  I could be wrong in saying most, but I should say many.